# ¿Editar un atributo de css "webkit-progress-bar" con javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Buenas, quiero saber cómo editar el componente "-webkit-progress-bar", el cual tengo declarado así:

```
.form progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #1EDC82;
}
```

Y lo tengo en esta parte del código:

```
<div class="progress">
<p>html 5</p>
<label for="html"></label>
<progress max="100" value="0" id="html"></progress>
</div>
```

Y quiero saber cómo editar el atributo del webkit con javascript, intenté esto:

```
document.getElementById("html").style.webkitBackground = "#FFF";
```

Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, a quien le pueda servir dejo lo que hice.
Primero añadí una clase al progress

```
<progress max="100" value="0" id="html" class="prim"></progress>
```

y edité el css para que el primer progress sea de la clase prim

```
.form progress.prim::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #1EDC82;
}
```

y además creé otro css parecido al anterior pero cambiando el background al color que quiero se coloque

```
.form progress.sec::-webkit-progress-value {
      background: red;
    }
```

Y con js lo que hago es cambiar la class "prim" por la class "sec" removiendo la primera clase.

```
$('#html').addClass("sec").removeClass("prim");
```

espero le sirva a alguien. Si conocen otra forma con gusto leeré sus comentarios. Cabe destacar que, al tener varios progress es mejor cambiar el class para que los otros progress mantengan su color.